# Prove that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty }\frac{1}{\log(\log(n))}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

How to prove this limit?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{1}{\log(\log(n))}=0$$
I thought of something like 
$$0 \le \frac{1}{\log(\log(n))} \le \frac{1}{n}$$
Is it alright?

Comment: Well, since $\;\log\log n\le\log n\le n\;$ I'd say: no, it isn't right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that

$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\log(n)=+\infty$

thus

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{\log(\log(n))}=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\frac{1}{\log(N)}=0$$

Answer (score 5):

Try this, let $n> e^{e^N}$. Then you have that

$${1\over\log\log n}< {1\over N}$$

So for any $\epsilon >0$, Choose $N>{1\over\epsilon}$ and then for all $n > e^{e^N}$ we have

$${1\over\log\log n}<\epsilon$$

showing the limit condition.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not alright since the inverse function reverse the inequalities.

But you have

$$\log(\log n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} +\infty$$

so

$$\frac{1}{\log(\log n)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0.$$

Comment: That's not enough, what about $f(x) = 4 - {1\over x}$ this is a strictly increasing function as well, but ${1\over f(x)}\to {1\over 4}$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @AdamHughes You are right, that was a wrong (and unnecessary !) argument.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\log x = \int_1^x {1 \over t} dt $, hence $\log$ is increasing. From the integral we see that $\log (n+1) \ge {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 3} + \cdots + { 1 \over n}$, and since the Harmonic series is divergent, we see that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \log x = \infty$.

It follows that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \log (\log x) = \infty$ and so
$\lim_{x \to \infty} {1 \over \log (\log x) } = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=2^{2^k}$ and note that $\ln \ln x$ is monotonic